# Pyside2 QScrollArea QLabel not expanding to include text

Tags: python, pyside2, qscrollarea

Using pyside2 and PyQt and I want to be able to do `label.setText()` in order to set text inside the scroll area. This seems fairly simple, but the issue is that when I run this it cuts off everything other then the first letter of the string sent to `.setText()` and doing `QSizePolicy` things doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Here's the code I currently have as my widgets class:

```
class widgets (QMainWindow) :
    def __init__ (self ) :
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.label1 = QLabel(self)
        self.scrollablel1 = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollablel1.setWidget(self.label1)

        self.label1.setText("foo \n bar \n 2000")
```

The result of this is

[image: this]

As you can see it cuts off all of the text except for the first little bit.

I've tried adding a few more things to no avail, such as:

```
self.label1.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
self.label1.setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding ,  QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding )
```

Answer (score 0):

Well been thinking/researching about this for a while now and am embarrassed to say I've just come across the solution. All you've got to do is add:

```
self.scrollablel1.setWidgetResizable(True)
```

And it works just fine!